# limit exceeded error while deploying

Tags: custom-field, limits, migration-tool, activities

I'm using Force.com Migration Tool to deploy Activity object's new fields to the target environment.

My **source has 100** fields in it's activity object (exact Activity custom field limit for the Edition is 100) and the **target org has 94** fields.

The only difference between these two objects is the newly added 6 fields in the source metadata files, all the other **94 fields are identical**.

**My problem is**, I am getting limit exceeded error while deploying the source to target org.

How could I resolve this issue?

**NOTE:** Target org's previous number of fields I had was 96, I deleted 2 fields and erased it from the recycle bin as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 96 + 6 makes 102. It is still > 100.

Comment: Oh! My bad it should be 94,

Comment: Its about math, not Salesforce :)

Comment: Yeh! I edited the post :)

Comment: Verify that all other 94 fields are same in source and target.

Comment: @Hasantha hey, we are also facing same issue as we deleted some fields on Activity object. Do you got any workaround for this?

Comment: @Rajasekar, This is long time back though, as I can remember we wait for couple of days and did the deployment again, I think salesforce took sometime  to cleanup the fields that we deleted and any history data for that field. Otherwise please raise a ticket with Salesforce.